# How to get a data range in a million rows dataset

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, grep

I have got a file with millions of rows which has this following pattern

```
01/02/1991,0931,7.13,7.13,7.13,7.13,8000

01/02/1991,0932,7.14,7.14,7.14,7.14,8000

01/02/1991,0935,7.16,7.16,7.16,7.16,3200

01/02/1991,0938,7.16,7.17,7.16,7.17,19200

01/02/1991,0941,7.19,7.19,7.19,7.19,200000 

01/02/1991,0956,7.19,7.19,7.19,7.19,8800
```

The date format is `mm/dd/YYYY`. How can I get only the data range between 01/01/2002 and 08/31/2008 and delete other lines? The dates 01/01/2002 and 08/31/2008 themselves may not be in the file.

I would like to do it in bash

Head File:

```
01/02/1991,0931,7.13,7.13,7.13,7.13,83200^M$
01/02/1991,0932,7.14,7.14,7.14,7.14,8000^M$
01/02/1991,0935,7.16,7.16,7.16,7.16,3200^M$
01/02/1991,0938,7.16,7.17,7.16,7.17,19200^M$
01/02/1991,0941,7.19,7.19,7.19,7.19,200000^M$
01/02/1991,0956,7.19,7.19,7.19,7.19,8800^M$
01/02/1991,0957,7.20,7.20,7.20,7.20,13600^M$
01/02/1991,0958,7.22,7.22,7.22,7.22,5600^M$
01/02/1991,1003,7.22,7.23,7.22,7.23,8000^M$
01/02/1991,1006,7.23,7.23,7.23,7.23,10400^M$
```

Comment: Are records already sorted by date?

Comment: Yes, they are already sorted

Comment: Are the lines actually double-spaced like that? BTW, that's not `bash`, it's `sed`. And your "attempt" is ridiculous. Have you even read the manual?

Comment: I am a newbie as regards sed and awk and i posted it here just because i was frustrated of trying different commands. I understand it is a ridiculous example but i put it there just to show i did my homework. Yes the file does not have that space in the middle

Comment: I need to have also the rows in the middle not only those related to those two dates, i will try them later

Comment: Both answers below print all the rows you want.

Comment: you didn't mean to delete the lines.. right, just get the range lines and ignore others!

Comment: Well, i wanted to create a new file with the valid lines to be honest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F, '$1=="01/02/2002"{p=1} $1=="01/08/2008"{p=2} $1!="01/08/2008" && p==2{exit} p' dataset.txt
```

Comment: Too bad the date is not formatted in a sensible YYYY-mm-dd format so you could write `$1 > "2008-08-31" {exit}`

Comment: Yes that would have been nice to have.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much indeed for your help. However I should say that the it does not do anything. It goes through the file but at the end of the process it has the same number of rows.

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino You need to redirect the output to another file.

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino: I actually tested it on OSX itself using is default BSD awk. `awk --version` give me: `awk version 20070501` and it worked pretty well with provided input. Are you sure your input file is same as shown in your question?

Comment: Just looked at the image you linked. Looks fine but I would prefer a text file sample that you can upload on http://pastebin.com site. Can you also show output of `head file | cat -vte` in your question.

Comment: @anubhava see the head in the post, [here](http://pastebin.com/RiP7amYb) a piece of the file. Of course that part does not match with your dates

Comment: The thing is this sample file only has `01/02/1991` data in all records and that is why awk won't get any records. Are you sure you have these 2 dates in the input file? Your `head` output is showing `^M` which is `\r` in each line though that won't create problem for my `awk` command.

Comment: Just make sure your input file has some matching dates for `01/01/2002` and `31/08/2008`. Test it out using `grep '01/01/2002' file` and `grep '31/08/2008' file` commands.

Comment: I tried the @glennjackman script and it gets data out. The data I need is in the range between the first and the last date. I do not need to know if my dataset has some lines with 01/01/2002 or 31/08/2008 but all the dates in the middle of this range. there is no line for 01/01/2002

Comment: @anubhava here the entire [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_5ZKgWelGWbkN0dWdyODhscDlJd0FkeW1kdDZkTldwU3d3/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: As I suspected before that both dates `01/01/2002 or 31/08/2008` don't exist in your input file. Try this command to make it work: **`awk -F, '$1=="01/02/2002"{p=1} p; $1=="01/08/2008"{exit}' AA.txt`**

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` proposal:

```
sed -n '\#01/01/2002#,\#31/08/2008#{p;d}; \#31/08/2008#p' \
   dataset.txt > newFile.txt
```

While lines are between patterns, print, delete from pattern space and exit. 1st line of ending pattern exits because of `d` so there's only one print. Following lines of ending pattern gets printed with second command.

Comment: But won't this only print the first record with the second date? What if there are more than one record with that date?

Comment: @ooga: All those records are printed for me (that's why I used `{N,p}`). Did you try it?

Comment: You caught me! I didn't run it. But now that I did, it seems to only print one extra repetition of a record with the second date. I.e., if there are 3 or more records with the end date, it only prints the first two. I'm removing my downvote, though, since it was careless of me to do that without running it. (EDIT: Apparently you can't remove a downvote after a certain amount of time. If you edit it I think I can. Maybe you can fix it.)

Comment: Here's one way of fixing it: `sed -n '\#01/01/2002#,\#31/08/2008#{p;d}; \#31/08/2008#p' file > outfile`

Comment: @ooga: You're right, I tested my code, but it appears that wasn't enough either. I edit my post with your fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative: compare the dates as times. This will be a lot slower than anubhava's solution. Requires GNU awk:

```
gawk -F, -v start_date=01/01/2002 -v end_date=08/31/2008 '
    function to_epoch(date) {
        #             ... year .....     ... month ......     ... day ........
        return mktime(substr(date,7) " " substr(date,1,2) " " substr(date,4,2) " 0 0 0")
    }
    BEGIN { start = to_epoch(start_date); end = to_epoch(end_date) }
    { t = to_epoch($1) }
    start <= t && t <= end
    t > end {exit}
' file
```

Comment: Ladies and gentleman, we have a winner......with some concerns. Your script is the only one that works properly....However, the script start getting data from 01/01/2000 not 2002. and finisch 19/01/2007 not 2008

Comment: Huh, not in my testing. Can you show a *minimal* sample of input to demonstrate this problem?

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. In your question, you told us the date format was `dd/mm/YYYY` -- it is actually `mm/dd/YYYY`. So `31/08/2008` never appears in the file!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '$1=="01/01/2002",$1=="31/08/2008" {print;next} $1=="31/08/2008" {print;next} {quit}' file
```

Added the extra `$1=="31/08/2008"` to print all records with that date (not just the first one ). And added the quit for efficiency. Improvements entirely due to anubhava.

Comment: Simple but doesn't work (it will print only first record with date `"31/08/2008"`

Comment: Wouldn't have commented otherwise.

Comment: @anubhava Oh, I see what you mean. Sorry. :-(

Comment: It works now but since OP talks about million of rows it would be better to call `exit` once record goes past `"31/08/2008"`

Comment: @anubhava Excellent point. Now I understand the complexity of your answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, but there is something wrong: awk: illegal statement
input record number 1, file AA.txt source line number 1. AA.txt is my file. Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino I don't get any error. Are you using GNU awk?

Comment: @ooga maybe the problem is due to the fact that macOSX uses the BSD version of the console. I will install homebrew and let you know soon